# Rails scope with join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models, `post` and `comment`

I need a scope on `post` called `in_use`, which is defined as being where there exists comments for that post. I'm sure this is completely simple but my mind is blank !

so I need to be able to do something like

```
Post where post.comments.count > 0
```

but have no idea how to do this in a scope?

Answer (score 2):

The best optimized way to do it:

```
scope :in_use, -> { where("exists (select * from comments where post_id=posts.id)") }
```

That'll optimize well in any rdbms and it'll optimize if the query is chained.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :in_use, -> { includes(:comments).where("post.comments <> ''") }
```

Comment: This is absolutely not correct sql and will not work.